# ERRO: fatal: unable to access... Could not resolve proxy

Tags: git, bitbucket

Temos aqui na empresa um repositório **Bitbucket** na *intranet*. Estou tentando fazer um clone do projeto porém está dando um erro estranho em relação ao ***proxy***. Já conversei com o setor de infraestrutura, e o pessoal disse que não tem nenhum ***proxy***. Inclusive o repositório está na intranet e disseram que não tem porque bater lá na internet para fazer tal verificação.

Estou executando o seguinte comando:

```
git clone http://fulano.de.tal@git.fulano.com.br:7990/scm/dk-bra/fulanosbarapi.git
```

Abaixo segue a resposta que o GIT me retorna:

```
Cloning into 'fulanosbarapi'... fatal: unable to access 
'http://fulano.de.tal@git.fulano.com.br:7990/scm/dk-bra/fulanosbarapi.git': 
Could not resolve proxy: proxy.edv.fulano.de
```

Eu usei o comando abaixo para excluir qualquer configuração de ***proxy*** no GIT, porém mesmo assim o erro persiste:

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

Fiz um teste em outra máquina para ver se era meu perfil, porém fez o clone corretamente. Apenas essa máquina que estou que acontece isso. Tentei procurar todos os resquícios deste PC para tentar encontrar nada, mas sem sucesso.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Verifique se existem as variáveis HTTP_PROXY e HTTPS_PROXY configuradas no teu ambiente.

Comment: @GiovanniNunes eu verifiquei e inclusive para garantir, usei o comando ai na descrição da pergunta para remover qualquer configuração de proxy. Você sabe se existe outra maneira de ver isso?

Comment: Nem sempre remover o proxy é a solução. Acredito que tu precises configurá-lo corretamente, conforme a rede da tua empresa requer. Eu, particularmente, começaria copiando as configurações de uma máquina que consegue concluir o clone...

Comment: Opa, eu falava das variáveis do shell (bash, ksh etc) que definem o proxy e não da configuração do Git e que são consultados por ele também: `HTTPS_PROXY=127.0.0.1:9000 git clone https://github.com/plainspooky/giovannireisnunes.git` e resultará no mesmo erro que você está obtendo: `fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/plainspooky/giovannireisnunes.git/': Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9000: Connection refused`

Comment: Eu estava com um problema semelhante, usando uma VM. Começou a dar esse erro misteriosamente. O Que fiz, foi salvar meu arquivo .gitignore, deletei a pasta do meu repositório e clonei-a novamente... Copiei meu arquivo .gitignore para dentro dela e tudo resolvido!